# US tourist / visitor visa for child (4yrs)

Tags: usa, visas, children

For an INDIAN national residing in UK (full time employed) what is the process to apply for a visitor visa of US for their child. The parents already have a long term US visitor visa issued for them so interested to know the process for child only.

Answer (score 2):

The child must have a passport (or refugee travel document) to travel, and in order to enter the US must have a US visa. If the child does not have a passport, you must apply for and secure one for the child before you travel.

After the child has a passport, then you apply for a US visa for the child. The child can travel to the US if a US visa is issued in the child's name. The visa application process begins online.

Note that this answer relates only to passport and visa issues. It does not address covid-related requirements or documents.